# How to query text-nodes from DOM, find markdown-patterns, replace matches with HTML-markup and replace the original text-node with the new content?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, markdown, textnode

## Markdown-like functionality for tooltips

#### Problem:

Using Vanilla JavaScript I want to:

Change this:

```
<div>
   <p>
        Hello [world]{big round planet we live on}, how is it [going]{verb that means walking}? 
   </p>
   <p>
        It is [fine]{a word that expresses gratitude}.
   </p>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Hello <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="big round planet we live on">world</mark>, how is it <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="verb means walking">world</mark>?
    </p>
    <p>
        It is fine <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="a word that expresses gratitude">thanks</mark>.
    </p>
</div>
```

so it looks visually like this:

[image]

is somehow similar to "markdown" edit functionalities.

#### Solution:

1. Mark the strings to replace in a different way:

```
<p>It is fine *[thanks]{a word that expresses gratitude}*!</p>
```

1. Initiate Bootstrap and [tooltip functionality](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/tooltips/).
2. Grab all paragraphs

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p')
```

3. Apply REGEX

```
tooltip = original.match(/(\{)(.*?)(\})/gi)[0].slice(1, -1);
hint = original.match(/(\[)(.*?)(\])/gi)[0].slice(1, -1);
```

4. Change their inside-text

```
replaced = original.replace(/(\*)(.*?)(\*)/gi, 
        `<mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="${tooltip}">${hint}</mark>`);
elem.innerHTML = replaced;
```

5. Alltogether in one function:

```
[].forEach.call(p, elem => {
    let original = elem.innerHTML;
    let replaced, tooltip, hint
    tooltip = original.match(/(\{)(.*?)(\})/gi)[0].slice(1, -1);
    hint = original.match(/(\[)(.*?)(\])/gi)[0].slice(1, -1);
    replaced = original.replace(/(\*)(.*?)(\*)/gi, 
        `<mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="${tooltip}">${hint}</mark>`);
      elem.innerHTML = replaced;
});
```

#### but I fail

Miserable when there is more paragraphs or when I just want to do it in an easy way with 2 pair of brackets instead of additional asterix. Fails also hen the innerTEXT has more phrases / words that should have the tooltip.
Any ideas?
Do you have any suggestions?
Existing ways of doing it?
Libraries?
Scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very easily can stumble at coming up with the right approach of how to replace a text node with other unknown HTML content.

A generic solution takes into account a more complex HTML content.

Thus, starting from a source-node, one stepwise needs to insert each of its child-nodes (either text- or element-nodes) before the targeted text-node. Once all nodes got inserted, one finally removes the targeted text-node.

Regarding the [regex and the markup template](https://regex101.com/r/aBPUAI/1/), one can create the markup-string within a single `replace` call from [a single regex and a single template string both making use of *Capturing Groups*](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#capturing-groups-in-replacement).

```js
// text node detection helper
function isNonEmptyTextNode(node) {
  return (
       (node.nodeType === 3)
    && (node.nodeValue.trim() !== '')
    && (node.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'script')
  );
}

// text node reducer functionality
function collectNonEmptyTextNode(list, node) {
  if (isNonEmptyTextNode(node)) {
    list.push(node);
  }
  return list;
}
function collectTextNodeList(list, elmNode) {
  return Array.from(
    elmNode.childNodes
  ).reduce(
    collectNonEmptyTextNode,
    list
  );
}

// final dom render function
function replaceTargetNodeWithSourceNodeContent(targetNode, sourceNode) {
  const parentNode = targetNode.parentNode;

  Array.from(sourceNode.childNodes).forEach(function (node) {
    parentNode.insertBefore(node, targetNode);
  });
  parentNode.removeChild(targetNode);    
}

// template and dom fragment render function
function findMarkdownCreateMarkupAndReplaceTextNode(node) {
  const regX = (/\[([^\]]+)\]\{([^\}]+)\}/g);
  const text = node.nodeValue;

  if (regX.test(text)) {
    const template = '<mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="$2">$1</mark>'

    const renderNode = document.createElement('div');
    renderNode.innerHTML = text.replace(regX, template);

    replaceTargetNodeWithSourceNodeContent(node, renderNode);
  }
}


const elementNodeList = Array.from(document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'));

const textNodeList = elementNodeList.reduce(collectTextNodeList, []);

textNodeList.forEach(findMarkdownCreateMarkupAndReplaceTextNode);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Hello [world]{big round planet we live on}, how is it [going]{verb that means walking}?</span>
    <span>Hello [world]{big round planet we live on}, how is it [going]{verb that means walking}?</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    <span>It is [fine]{a word that expresses gratitude}.</span>
    It is [fine]{a word that expresses gratitude}.
    <span>It is [fine]{a word that expresses gratitude}.</span>
  </p>
</div>
<!--

  // does get rerendered into:

  <div>
    <p>
      <span>
        Hello
        <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="big round planet we live on">
          world
        </mark>
        , how is it
        <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="verb that means walking">
          going
        </mark>
        ?
      </span>
      <span>
        Hello
        <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="big round planet we live on">
          world
        </mark>
        , how is it
        <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="verb that means walking">
          going
        </mark>
        ?
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>
        It is
        <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="a word that expresses gratitude">
          fine
        </mark>
        .
      </span>
      It is
      <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="a word that expresses gratitude">
        fine
      </mark>
      .
      <span>
        It is
        <mark data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="a word that expresses gratitude">
          fine
        </mark>
        .
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>

//-->
```

Comment: This solution and answer is amazing. Where can I learn more about nodes and their usage? Thank you!

Comment: One just needs to know where to look this stuff up. I do not memorize entire specs either ... [MDN > Web APIs > Node :: Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node#Methods). And if the solution was that amazing you might consider flagging it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Done! Thank you again.